# Email Regex Match with [dot] for "." & [at] for "@"

Tags: regex, regex-group

How can I match all the emails listed below through regex:

```
maddy@gmail.com
ma123.23ddy(at)gmail.com
mad12-213dy@gmail(dot)com
ma123ddy[at]gmail[dot]com
mad123dy@gmail[dot]com 
maddy[at]gmail.com
rc.joshi62@gov[dot]ab.ws.com
rc.joshi62[at]gov.ab.ws.com
rc.joshi62[at]gov[dot]ab.ws.com
rc.joshi62@gov.ab.ws.com

c.123.joshi62(at)gov(dot)ab.ws.com
rc123.jo123shi62(at)gov.ab.ws.com
r123c.joshi62@gov(dot)ab.ws.com
c.123[dot]joshi62(at)gov(dot)ab[dot]ws[dot]com
rc123(dot)jo123shi62(at)gov(dot)ab(dot)ws(dot)com
rc123(dot)jo123shi62[at]gov(dot)ab(dot)ws(dot)com
r123c(dot)joshi62[at]gov(dot)ab[dot]ws[dot]com
```

I'm trying to match all the complex email id's mentioned in the source code of this site:view-source:https://www.panchayat.gov.in/web/guest/who-s-is-who
I'm currently using this Regex as mentioned below:

```html
\b[A-Z0-9._%+-]+@[[A-Z0-9.-]+\.[A-Z]{2,}\b
```

Comment: just use: '(@|\[at\])' instead of '@', the same for dot. It means '@' OR '[at]'.

Comment: Oh, sorry the comment turned out wrong, the '[' and ']' MUST BE ESCAPED (but it doesn't show here.

Comment: I implemented this Regex based on your suggestions `\b[A-Z0-9._%+-]+(@|[at])[[A-Z0-9.-]+\.(.|[dot])[A-Z]{2,}\b` . It's not working. Please provide the regex

Comment: Did you mean to write `[dot].`?  If not try https://regex101.com/r/JDAY6O/1

Comment: @MDR Can you please update the Regex to match `rc.joshi62@gov[dot]ab.ws.com` as well. I've updated the question. Please accept my apologies

Comment: Maybe: https://regex101.com/r/JDAY6O/2

Comment: After your most recent edit as of writing: https://regex101.com/r/JDAY6O/3

Comment: Thank you @MDR. I'm really sorry but I've one more use case `c.joshi62(at)gov(dot)ab.ws.com
rc.joshi62(at)gov.ab.ws.com
rc.joshi62@gov(dot)ab.ws.com`

Comment: Maybe: https://regex101.com/r/JDAY6O/4

Comment: This should work: \b[A-Z0-9._%+-]+(@|\\[at\\]|\\(at\\))[A-Z0-9.-]+((\\.|\\[dot\\]|\\(dot\\))[A-Z]{2,})+\b

Comment: @PoulBak It's leaving some of the emails like `maddy@gmail.com
maddy(at)gmail.com maddy[at]gmail.com  rc.joshi62[at]gov.ab.ws.com rc.joshi62@gov.ab.ws.com rc.joshi62(at)gov.ab.ws.com`

Comment: I hate this formatting: There is a double escaping before the dot (in my comment), it should only by one escape, remove the extra.

Comment: Thank you @PoulBak

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, here it is:
The regex:

```
\b[A-Z0-9._%+-]+(@|\[at\]|\(at\))[A-Z0-9.-]+((\.|\[dot\]|\(dot\))[A-Z]{2,})+\b
```

Compared to your own regex, this simply add `alternations` (meaning OR).
I add:

```
(@|\[at\]|\(at\))
```

which will match an `'@`' OR '`[at]`' OR '`(at)`'.

For dot I add:

```
(\.|\[dot\]|\(dot\))
```

which will match a `dot` OR '`[dot]`' OR '`(dot)`'

I then made a group of:

```
((\.|\[dot\]|\(dot\))[A-Z]{2,})+
```

which will match things like: '.com' and '.uk.com' one or more times.

**Update:**
I updated the regex to support '.' or '(dot)' or '[dot]' in the name before '@':

```
\b[A-Z0-9._%+-]+((\.|\[dot\]|\(dot\))[A-Z0-9._%+-]+)*(@|\[at\]|\(at\))[A-Z0-9.-]+((\.|\[dot\]|\(dot\))[A-Z]{2,})+\b
```

Now it matches all the examples in the question.

BTW: The mistake you made in your recent regex is to include everything in a `character group` (between square brackets). That will match every `character` in the group, in any order.

**Update 2:**

Ups, typo, updated the regex.

Comment: Hello Poul! Thank you for providing the regex. I was trying to match all the emails mentioned on the source code of this website: view-source:https://www.panchayat.gov.in/web/guest/who-s-is-who. But I was missing on some of the more advanced email Use Cases. I've added some of them in the question also. But complete list can be found at view-source:https://www.panchayat.gov.in/web/guest/who-s-is-who.

Comment: I've updated the Regex: `\b[A-Z0-9._%+-\[at\]|\(dot\)|\[dot\]|\[hyphen\]|\[Hyphen\]]+(@|\[at\]|\(at\))[A-Z0-9.-]+((\.|\[dot\]|\(dot\))[A-Z]{2,})+\b` But it's still selecting [nbsp;chander(dot)singh99(at)nic(dot)in] & [td>baljeet(dot)k(at)gov(dot)in]. HTML elements are also getting included using the regex I've updated

Answer (score 1):

Given these strings...

```
maddy@gmail.com
maddy[at]gmail[dot]com
maddy@gmail[dot]com
maddy[at]gmail.com
rc.joshi62@gov[dot]ab.ws.com
rc.joshi62[at]gov.ab.ws.com
rc.joshi62[at]gov[dot]ab.ws.com
rc.joshi62.gov.ab.ws.com
c.joshi62(at)gov(dot)ab.ws.com
rc.joshi62(at)gov.ab.ws.com
rc.joshi62@gov(dot)ab.ws.com
```

The following regex matches the string if it's on its own line...

```
^([\w\d]+\.)?[\w\d]+(@|\[at\]|\(at\))?[\w\d]+(\.|\[dot\]|\(dot\))[\w\d]{2,}(\.[\w\d]+\.[\w\d]+)?(\.[\w\d]+)?$
```

If the email appears in a larger string but has spaces (word boundaries before and after) try...

```
\b([\w\d]+\.)?[\w\d]+(@|\[at\]|\(at\))?[\w\d]+(\.|\[dot\]|\(dot\))[\w\d]{2,}(\.[\w\d]+\.[\w\d]+)?(\.[\w\d]+)?\b
```

Comment: Thank you @MDR. It's working based on the emails I listed. Please accept my apologies. But when I looked at my data, there some numbers also. I've updated my question

Comment: I think you have almost removed your question.  What are the new strings?

Comment: I've updated the question. I somehow missed on something

Comment: See new answer that I've posted

Comment: `[\w\d]` is better written `\w`

Answer (score 0):

Given these strings...

```
maddy@gmail.com
ma123.23ddy(at)gmail.com
mad12-213dy@gmail(dot)com
ma123ddy[at]gmail[dot]com
mad123dy@gmail[dot]com 
maddy[at]gmail.com
rc.joshi62@gov[dot]ab.ws.com
rc.joshi62[at]gov.ab.ws.com
rc.joshi62[at]gov[dot]ab.ws.com
rc.joshi62@gov.ab.ws.com
c.123.joshi62(at)gov(dot)ab.ws.com
rc123.jo123shi62(at)gov.ab.ws.com
r123c.joshi62@gov(dot)ab.ws.com
c.123[dot]joshi62(at)gov(dot)ab[dot]ws[dot]com
rc123(dot)jo123shi62(at)gov(dot)ab(dot)ws(dot)com
rc123(dot)jo123shi62[at]gov(dot)ab(dot)ws(dot)com
r123c(dot)joshi62[at]gov(dot)ab[dot]ws[dot]com
```

Try...

```
\b([\w\d]+)?(\.)?([-])?[\w\d]+(\.)?[\w\d]+(@|\[at\]|\(at\))?[\w\d]+(\.|\[dot\]|\(dot\))[\w\d]{2,}(\.[\w\d]+\.[\w\d]+)?(\.[\w\d]+)?\b
```

UPDATE: Cleaned up version...

```
\b[\w\d.-]+(@|\[at\]|\(at\))[\w\d]+(\[dot\]|\(dot\)|\.)[\w\d.-]+\b
```

Comment: Added a shorter version after reviewing the 13 strings provided.

Comment: Hello MDR! Thank you for providing the regex. I was trying to match all the emails mentioned on the source code of this website: view-source:panchayat.gov.in/web/guest/who-s-is-who. But I was missing on some of the more advanced email Use Cases. I've added some of them in the question also. But complete list can be found at view-source:panchayat.gov.in/web/guest/who-s-is-who. Can you have a look into it once

Comment: Given that a valid email must have an `@` symbol or `[at]` or `(at)` I would go with https://regex101.com/r/YaNjh6/1 but I have pulled a couple of the listed emails to the top as these don't have any style of `@` so technically they are not valid email addresses.  Example of an invalid email search the page you linked for `ashish` and notice the email in the table has no style of `@`.

Comment: Hello MDR! While I was checking on the provided at this site >>  https://www.panchayat.gov.in/web/guest/who-s-is-who . Some of the emails like [ ooja[dot]sharma80[at]nic[dot]in] & [nilarora[dot]k[at]gov[dot]in ] were not detected by the Regex

Comment: I've updated the Regex: `\b[A-Z0-9._%+-\[at\]|\(dot\)|\[dot\]|\[hyphen\]|\[Hyphen\]]+(@|\[at\]|\(at\))[A-Z0-9.-]+((\.|\[dot\]|\(dot\))[A-Z]{2,})+\b` But it's still selecting [nbsp;chander(dot)singh99(at)nic(dot)in] & [td>baljeet(dot)k(at)gov(dot)in]. HTML elements are also getting included using the regex I've updated

Comment: I've just grabbed the HTML from the page (that site has SSL errors that seems to block Firefox).  However, the regex `[\w\[\(\]\)\.-]+(@|\[at\]|\(at\))[\w\[\(\]\)\.-]+(com|in)` looks fine to me.  It was the previous regex but with `^` and `$` removed from the beginning and the end and the unnecessary `\d` removed.

Comment: for example chander(dot)singh99(at)nic(dot)in is selected correctly.  Example: https://postimg.cc/K37s5t1V